# Could not write JSON: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, google-cloud-spanner

That is what I got:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-18T08:40:13.977+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"promotion\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1[\"content\"]->com.gk.promo.models.promotion.Promotion[\"location\"])",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"promotion\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1[\"content\"]->com.gk.promo.models.promotion.Promotion[\"location\"])\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:289)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:114)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"promotion\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1[\"content\"]->com.gk.promo.models.promotion.Promotion[\"location\"])\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanSerializer.serialize(UnwrappingBeanSerializer.java:120)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.java:127)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(SerializerProvider.java:1033)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:202)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:150)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:718)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:639)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer.serialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:349)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalResourcesSerializer.serialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:308)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)\r\n\t... 64 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gk.promo.models.location.Location!\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities$$Lambda$1311/331092961.get(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:95)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer.toResource(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:386)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer.serialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:370)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)\r\n\t... 87 more\r\n",
    "path": "/apipromocentral/promotions"
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well the error message couldn't really be much clearer.

Comment: I have edited the stack trace with not formatted one

Comment: Hi, Could you include the definition of Location? I think its having problems casting your custom class to a JSON object.

Comment: Hi, Please find the POJO for the location                                                  
@Data
public class Location {
  /**
   * identifier
   */
  private String identifier;
  /**
   * name
   */
  private String name;
  /**
   * name
   */
  private LocationType type;
  
  /**
   * exclusion list
   * This help excluding location
   */
  private List<Location> exclusionList;
}

Comment: Location has a List<Location> as a attribute?

Comment: Yes Juancki. It is private List<Location> exclusionList;

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are having a list of type `Location` class and the class consist of different fields. You then fill this list with data and try to add this list to your Cloud Spanner and then you are getting the `Couldn't find PersistentEntity`, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: It seems that the data that you are trying to submit in your Cloud Spanner database is inconsistent with the schema or with the data type. I think the documentation that you should follow is the [Adding Spring Data Cloud Spanner to an application](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/adding-spring). Can you please check if your are using the structure correctly. Also check the supported [data types](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-types#array-type). Please update the description and include a minimum reproduction code.

Comment: Hi Andrei Cusnir, I was not able to consistently reproduce the issue and that made very difficult to understand the issue. To resolve this, I used to post a new request and that use to solve the issue. I did follow the documentation that you have mentioned above.

Comment: So you only get this issue some times and not constantly. And whenever you are getting the issue, you just retry to call the API and the issue is resolved at that moment?

Comment: GET call is getting resolved after inserting a new record with a post method call.

Comment: I was checking again the class that you have submitted previously and I can see that you are declaring the class `Location` and then you are creating a list inside that class of type `Location`. Reproducing this part is not possible in my side as including the class itself was not possible. I would recommend changing the class name as it seems the issue to be there instead of Cloud Spanner side. Change  `@Data public class Location` to `@Data public class LocationClass` that so the  `private List<Location>` within won't get conflict.

Comment: Hey Andrei, It is a valid way of declaring a class as an attribute of the enclosing class. Let me give you an example of the same An Employee will have a manager and that manager is also an Employee of the enclosing class.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this class and indeed you can specify the class as an attribute of itself. I believe at this point is a little bit difficult to continue with the investigation of the issue without some code snippet. Even if the issue is transient, please update the description and share the minimum code. Please include: 1. Class declaration, Example of filling the class (fake data) and the exact method that you call to submit the data to the Cloud Spanner database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"your.repositories.package"})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to explain it a little bit.

Comment: Exception is complaining about a missing entity **not** a missing repository so this will not address the issue. `@EntityScan` might however.